# Meaning of a long exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, intuition, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

***Edit:*** The setting for the question is some abelian category.

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864237/what-is-a-short-exact-sequence-telling-me) I learned that one way to view a short exact sequence $$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$$ is as saying that $B$ is an extension of $C$ by $A$. This makes sense to me and has been very helpful, but now I'm at a loss as far as what long exact sequences are telling me. I know they're very useful because they relate the arrows they involve, thereby allowing for calculation, but I was hoping for a simple interpretation not too dissimilar from the one for short exact sequences.

As a particular case, what is the geometric interpretation of the relative homology long exact sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always break up a long exact sequence into small exact sequences. Suppose your long exact sequence is:
$$\dots \to A_{n+1} \xrightarrow{f_{n+1}} A_n \xrightarrow{f_n} A_{n-1} \xrightarrow{f_{n-1}} A_{n-2} \to \dots,$$
then you can split it as:
$$0 \to \operatorname{coker} f_{n+1} \xrightarrow{f_n} A_{n-1} \xrightarrow{f_{n-1}} \operatorname{im} f_{n-1} \to 0.$$
Proving this is a bit tedious, but it follows directly from the definitions. So in some sense a long exact sequence lets you think of $A_{n-1}$ as an extension of the image of $f_{n-1}$ by the cokernel of $f_{n+1}$.

But as you can see that's not really insightful, and remembering the correct indices at all is a feat in itself (I had to revise what I wrote three times and I'm still not 100% sure). In this context long exact sequences are more of a computational tool than anything. As you say they're very useful, but giving them an interpretation like for short ones doesn't really work, in my opinion.

In homological algebra [chain complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_complex) are the basic objects of study, and a long exact sequence is a chain complex with zero homology; just like a space can have trivial homology but be very interesting, so can chain complexes...

---

I'd just like to point out an additional thing: there is something called the [$\operatorname{Ext}$ functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor) that classifies extensions, that is if $A, B$ are modules over some ring $R$, then $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(A,B)$ classifies extensions of the form $0 \to B \to X \to A \to 0$ (for some suitable notion of isomorphism of such extensions, see Wikipedia for details). More generally the $n$th $\operatorname{Ext}$ functor $\operatorname{Ext}^n_R(A,B)$ classifies extensions of the type:
$$0 \to B \to X_n \to \dots \to X_1 \to A \to 0$$
so in some sense you can think of **bounded** long exact sequences as higher extensions. (If you think about it, this is very related to the splitting I talked about at the beginning, that would allow you to do proofs by induction on the length of the sequence...)

Comment: I'm confused about the decomposition of long exact sequences as $0 \to \operatorname{coker} f_{n+1} \xrightarrow{f_n} A_{n-1} \xrightarrow{f_{n-1}} \operatorname{im} f_{n-1} \to 0$, how can the arrows be $f_n,f_{n-1}$ for instance? I can only think of using epi-mono factorizations but that gives me a different (and not very enlightening result). Could you refer me to a textbook treatment?

Comment: @Exterior The notation is a bit abusive, the arrows are *induced* by $f_n$ and $f_{n-1}$. For $f_{n-1}$ that's easy (every arrow factors through its image), while for $f_n$ you have to use the universal property of the cokernel and the fact that $\operatorname{im} f_{n+1} \subset \ker f_n$ (the equality is used to say that the induced arrow is in fact injective). For a textbook... Maybe Weibel covers it (probably as an exercise)? I don't know, actually.

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/Qc6Iwrq.png?1) is the decomposition I see. Where do the cokernels come from?

Comment: It's a general fact that if $f : A \to B$, then $A / \ker f \cong \operatorname{im} f$ (first isomorphism theorem, basically). So if $\ker f = \operatorname{im} g$, then $\operatorname{coker} g := A / \operatorname{im} g = A / \ker f \cong \operatorname{im} f$.

Comment: The setting here is just some abelian category. I thought the first isomorphism theorem in abelian categories is just the epi-mono factorization, and says nothing about the kernel. (I'll edit the question to explicitly say the setting is an abelian category)

Comment: @Exterior In an abelian category, epimorphisms are [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_morphism). Think about it (or read the wikipedia page) and you'll see why this implies the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I think the fact exactness is autodual ($\mathrm{coim}f=\mathrm{coker}g \iff \mathrm{im} g= \mathrm{ker} f$) along with the image-coimage isomorphism provide the isomorphism of the *objects* $\mathrm{Im} f\cong \mathrm{Coker}g$. Is this also correct?

Comment: Also, the decomposition in the picture in my previous comment is wrong at least because the order of each epi-mono factorization is wrong.