# Exact short sequence vs exact long sequence?

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence

could anyone explain me what exactly the difference between an exact long sequence and an exact short sequence is? I think it pertains to homology theory, right?

Comment: A short exact sequence has only 3 non-trivial objects (and 2 maps), while a long exact sequence will have more (and therefore be .. longer!)

Comment: For an explanation and examples see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence).

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095611/meaning-of-a-long-exact-sequence/1096186#1096186

Answer (score 0):

A short exact sequence has finite length (usually five terms). A long exact sequence has infinitely many terms.

Comment: Any idea of its application to human language?

Comment: @JavierArias no. I'd be shocked if it had any such application in the sense I mean. Perhaps the source you are using isn't using the terms in the same way an algebraist would.

Comment: Could it no be possible to define some language string sequences or syntax in those terms?

Comment: @JavierArias I really don't know.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway.